# Application shortcuts in home folder for Message-Menu

Tags: 11.04, messaging-menu

I like other applications in my Message-Menu (e.g. Thunderbird, XChat, Skype), so I have created hortcuts for those applications in folder `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`.

To avoid restoring those shortcuts after every fresh install of Ubuntu, I would like to know if there is a user-related path inside the home folder where to move them (like the Application folders for the Gnome menu items).
I keep my home folder into a separate partition, so I don't have to restore my settings after every installations.

E.g.: you can customize for instance your menu settings using home folder `~/.local/share/applications`. Launchers in this folder will override the ones in root folder `/usr/share/applications`, plus they will be kept after a fresh install if your home is in a separate partition or if you back it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no-one comes up with a better answer you can always use a symbolic link (or symlink) (command [ln](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ln.1.html)). It only takes 3 steps:

- Create a directory inside `~/.local/share/`. For instance:`mkdir ~/.local/share/my_shortcuts/`
- Move the files you made into this new directory.  `mv /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/{my_shortcuts} ~/.local/share/my_shortcuts/`
- And to finish it off you can make a link to the directory where you moved them from with `ln ~/.local/share/my_shortcuts/{shortcut} /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/{shortcut}`

You need to do this with every shortcut and when you change one the other gets changed too. After a re-install all you need to do is re-create the symlinks (save the commands in an executable (text) file in your home directory and you can execute them after re-installing).

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind: symlinks seem to be suitable workaround.
I was looking for a more "native" way ;>)